# Electronic polarizability in Hohenber and Kohn DFT paper

Tags: density-functional-theory

I try to reproduce Eq.(31) in Hohenberg and Kohn's paper Inhomogeneous Electron Gas [(*Phys. Rev.* **136**, B864 (1964))](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.136.B864). My understanding to this model is that the external positive charge background(Eq.(27) in the paper) plays the  rule as a perturbation to the electron density and in the Hamiltonian we have a perturbation term:

$$\delta H = -\int \frac{n_{ext}(\boldsymbol{r^{'}})}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r^{'}}|} \text d^3\boldsymbol{r^{'}}.$$

What I did is:

Firstly, I write $\delta H$ into second quantization form and do Fourier transformation(the definition of $a(\boldsymbol{q})$ and $\rho_{\boldsymbol{q}}$ are given by Eq.(27) and Eq.(30) in the paper):
$$\delta H = -\int \frac{n_{ext}(\boldsymbol{r^{'}})}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r^{'}}|} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r})\hat{\psi}(\boldsymbol{r})\text d^3\boldsymbol{r^{'}}\text d^3\boldsymbol{r}\\
=\sum_{\boldsymbol{q},\boldsymbol{k}}\frac{4\pi a(\boldsymbol{q})}{\boldsymbol{q}}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{\boldsymbol{k}-\boldsymbol{q}}\hat{c_{\boldsymbol{k}}}\\
=\sum_{\boldsymbol{q}}\frac{4\pi a(\boldsymbol{q})}{\boldsymbol{q}}\rho_{\boldsymbol{q}}$$

Then, I also express the electron charge density operator in second quantization momentum operator:
$$\hat{n}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\boldsymbol{r})\hat{\psi}(\boldsymbol{r}) = \sum_{\boldsymbol{q^{'}}}e^{-i\boldsymbol{q^{'}}\boldsymbol{r}}\rho_{\boldsymbol{q^{'}}}.$$

Then I write down the 1st order perturbation of the ground state $|0\rangle$:
$$|0^{(1)}\rangle = \sum_{i\neq 0} \frac{\langle i|\delta H|0\rangle}{E_0-E_i}$$

Finally, I calculate the expectation value of the density operator for the perturbed ground state $|0\rangle + |0^{(1)}\rangle$ to first order. The perturbation to the electron density is:
$$\sum_{n\neq 0}\frac{\langle i|\delta H |0^{(1)}\rangle\langle 0^{(1)}|\hat{n}|i\rangle  + \langle i|\hat{n} |0^{(1)}\rangle\langle 0^{(1)}|\delta H|i\rangle}{E_0-E_i}......(a)$$

Substitute the expression of $\delta H$ and $\hat{n}$ to the equation (a), I found $b_1(\boldsymbol{q})$ in the paper can be written as:
$$b_1(\boldsymbol{q^{'}})=-\sum_{\boldsymbol{q}} \frac{4\pi a(\boldsymbol{q})}{\boldsymbol{q}} \sum_{i\neq 0}\frac{\langle i |\rho_{\boldsymbol{q}}|0\rangle\langle 0|\rho_{\boldsymbol{q^{'}}}|i\rangle + \langle i |\rho_{\boldsymbol{q^{'}}}|0\rangle\langle 0|\rho_{\boldsymbol{-q}}|i\rangle}{E_0-E_i}$$

I stopped here as I cannot find any way to go from equation above to Eq.(31) in the paper. If I can show that
$$\sum_{i\neq 0}\frac{\langle i |\rho_{\boldsymbol{q}}|0\rangle\langle 0|\rho_{\boldsymbol{q^{'}}}|i\rangle}{E_0-E_i} = 0$$ except $q = -q^{'}$, then the problem resolved. However, I don't think this is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first quantization:
\begin{align}
    \delta\hat{H}&=-\int_{V}\frac{n_{ext}(\mathbf{r}')}{\vert \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\vert}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r'}\equiv\hat{f}^{(1)}(\mathbf{r})
\end{align}
In second quantization it reads:
\begin{align}
    \delta\hat{H}&=\int_V\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{f}^{(1)}(\mathbf{r})\hat{\Psi}(\mathbf{r})=\int_V\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{-i\mathbf{k\cdot\mathbf{r}}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}~\hat{f}^{(1)}(\mathbf{r})~\sum_{\mathbf{k}'}\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{i\mathbf{k'\cdot\mathbf{r}}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}\\&=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}\frac{1}{V}\int_V\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}e^{-i (\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')\cdot\mathbf{r}}\hat{f}^{(1)}(\mathbf{r})\\&=\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}'}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}\frac{1}{V}\int_V\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}e^{-i (\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')\cdot\mathbf{r}}\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\bigg(-\frac{\lambda}{V}\bigg)\frac{a(\mathbf{q})e^{-i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}'}}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\vert}\\&=
    -\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\int_{V\times V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}'\frac{e^{-i(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')\cdot\mathbf{r}}e^{-i\mathbf{q\cdot\mathbf{r}'}}}{\vert\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\vert}
\end{align}
Next, we define
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{t}\\\mathbf{T}
    \end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1 \\1 &1
    \end{pmatrix}}_{\det = 1}\begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf{r}\\\mathbf{r}'
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
So that
\begin{align}
    \delta\hat{H}&=
    -\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V\times V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{T}\frac{e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')\cdot(\mathbf{t}+\mathbf{T})}e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\mathbf{q\cdot(\mathbf{T}-\mathbf{t})}}}{\sqrt{2}\vert\mathbf{t}\vert}
    \\&=
    -\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V\times V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{T}\frac{e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{t}}e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}((\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')+\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{T}}}{\sqrt{2}\vert\mathbf{t}\vert}
\end{align}
Short moment to remember that
\begin{align}
    \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\xi x}\mathrm{d}x=\delta(\xi)
\end{align}
to perform the integral in $\mathbf{T}$ yielding
\begin{align}
    \delta\hat{H}&=    -\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\frac{e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{t}}\delta(\sqrt{2}^{-1}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'+\mathbf{q}))}{\sqrt{2}\vert  \mathbf{t}\vert}
~8\pi^3
\\&=-\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\frac{e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{t}}\delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'+\mathbf{q})}{\sqrt{2}^{-3}\sqrt{2}\vert \mathbf{t}\vert}8\pi^3\\&\Rightarrow \frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\mapsto\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}}{8\pi^3}
\\&=-\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\int\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{k}}{8\pi^3}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}\frac{e^{-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{t}}\delta(\mathbf{k}-(\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q}))}{\vert \mathbf{t}\vert}32\pi^3\\&=-\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\frac{e^{\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(2\mathbf{q})\cdot\mathbf{t}}}{\vert  \mathbf{t}\vert}4
\\&=-\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{1}{2}\int_{V}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{t}\frac{e^{i\sqrt{2}\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{t}}}{\vert\mathbf{t}\vert}4\\&=-\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}',\mathbf{q}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}'-\mathbf{q}}c_{\mathbf{k}'}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{16\pi}{4\vert \mathbf{q}\vert^2}=-\frac{\lambda}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\rho_\mathbf{q}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{4\pi}{\vert \mathbf{q}\vert^2}=\delta\hat{H}
\end{align}
For the last line see e.g. [here](https://blog.cupcakephysics.com/electromagnetism/math%20methods/2014/10/04/the-fourier-transform-of-the-coulomb-potential.html.)

Next consider (see, e.g., Gasiorowicz)
\begin{equation}
    \vert\Psi_0^{appr}\rangle=\vert\psi_0\rangle+\sum_{l\neq 0}\frac{\langle\psi_l\vert\delta\hat{H}\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}\vert\psi_l\rangle
\end{equation}

The density operator in second quantization is
\begin{equation}
    \hat{n}(\mathbf{r})=\hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\Psi}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{k}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}'}e^{-i\underbrace{(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}')}_{=: \mathbf{q}}\mathbf{r}}c^\dagger_\mathbf{k}c_\mathbf{k'}
\end{equation}
which implies $\mathbf{k}=\mathbf{k}'+\mathbf{q}$
\begin{equation}
    \hat{n}(\mathbf{r})=\hat{\Psi}^\dagger(\mathbf{r})\hat{\Psi}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\sum_{\mathbf{k}'}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}'+\mathbf{q}}c_\mathbf{k'}=\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}}\rho_{-\mathbf{q}}
\end{equation}

So next we compute $\langle\Psi_0^{approx}\vert\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})\vert\Psi_0^{approx}\rangle$ to leading order in $\lambda$:
\begin{align}
    \langle\Psi_0^{approx}\vert\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})\vert\Psi_0^{approx}\rangle&=\langle\psi_0\vert\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})\vert\psi_0\rangle+2\sum_{l\neq 0}\langle\psi_l\vert\frac{\langle\psi_l\vert\delta\hat{H}\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}\cdot\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})\cdot\vert\psi_0\rangle
    \\&=n_0(\mathbf{r})+2\sum_{l\neq 0}\frac{\langle\psi_0\vert\delta\hat{H}\vert\psi_l\rangle\langle\psi_l\vert\hat{n}(\mathbf{r})\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}
    \\&=n_0(\mathbf{r})+2\sum_{l\neq 0}\frac{1}{V}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}}\frac{\langle\psi_0\vert\delta\hat{H}\vert\psi_l\rangle\langle\psi_l\vert\rho_{-\mathbf{q}}\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}
    \\&=n_0(\mathbf{r})-2\sum_{l\neq 0}\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\sum_{\mathbf{q}'}\frac{4\pi}{q'^2}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}}a(\mathbf{q}')\frac{\langle\psi_0\vert\rho_{\mathbf{q}'}\vert\psi_l\rangle\langle\psi_l\vert\rho_{-\mathbf{q}}\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}
    \\&=
    n_0(\mathbf{r})-2\sum_{l\neq 0}\frac{\lambda}{V^2}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\frac{4\pi}{q^2}e^{-i\mathbf{q}\mathbf{r}}a(\mathbf{q})\frac{\langle\psi_0\vert\rho_{\mathbf{q}}\vert\psi_l\rangle\langle\psi_l\vert\rho_{-\mathbf{q}}\vert\psi_0\rangle}{\epsilon_l-\epsilon_0}
\end{align}

The key in the last step is that the excited state $\vert\psi_l\rangle$ appears in both factors. Therefore the excitement operator $\hat{\rho}_{\mathbf{q}'}$ yields nonzero values only if $\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{q'}$.

In other words, the term to the right
is exciting one particle to an orbital distant $+\mathbf{q}$, whereas the term to the left is de-exciting a particle to an orbital distant $-\mathbf{q}'$; on the other hand, the index $l$ for the excited state is “locked” (equal in both terms) and therefore the only case in which neither one of the two inner products is zero is if $\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{q}'$.

Finally, we notice that it seems that we are off HK's result by volume factor. However, [Mermin](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.137.A1441), who quotes them, seems to have the same prefactor in agreement with what derived here.